How can I convert an Ultra HDR image to JXR, retaining HDR information?
I would like to make use of the HDR wallpaper support on Windows 11. I want to set the wallpaper to an image that I have taken on my Android phone, which is saved in Ultra HDR format (.jpg file extension, property "Ultra HDR" in Google Photos).
The image clearly has HDR content when viewed in Google Chrome, which has support for the Ultra HDR format. However, as of now (2024) Windows only supports HDR wallpapers when they are .jxr files.
Common image-processing programs have either no support for one of the formats involved, or worse, will ignore HDR data somehow. GIMP seems to ignore the HDR gainmap data in the Ultra HDR image, and ImageMagick will crash or create a washed-out looking image with standard maximum luminance.
How can I convert my Ultra HDR (JPEG_R) image to a JXR file?
